# Bookmarklet to fill a form with information taken from another website

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

My clients are real estate agents. They publish real estate ads on their websites using the website admin. Then they publish (quite) the same ads on a national property website. Of course they would like to be DRY and don't do the work twice.

I've thought about a bookmarklet they would click while they are on the property website form. Their real estates would be shown in a list and they would select one of them. Then the form will be filled with information received via the agent website API.

Do you think this is something possible? Is it the best way of doing this?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can try to do it. First you can load external script:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='** your external file URL here **';})();
```

You can create dynamic JS file that will define your agent id by GET variable in url, or create global variable. What JS script will do its up to you.